# Sleeping barber in Clojure

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'm implementing [Sleeping barber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem) using `core.async`. My current code is:

```
(def workingtime 10000)

(defn barber [in waiting-room]
  (go-loop [served-customers 0]
           (let [[v] (alts! [waiting-room in])]
             (if (= v :close)
               served-customers
               (do (Thread/sleep 20)
                   (recur (inc served-customers)))))))

(defn customers [in waiting-room]
  (go-loop [customers-overall 0]
           (let [customer-arrival-interval (timeout (+ 10 (rand-int 20)))
                 [v] (alts! [in customer-arrival-interval])]
             (if (= v :close)
               customers-overall
               (do (>! waiting-room :customer)
                   (recur (inc customers-overall)))))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [in (chan)
        waiting-room (chan (dropping-buffer 3))
        barber-ch (barber in waiting-room)
        customers-ch (customers in waiting-room)]
    (println "opening the shop for 10 seconds...")
    (Thread/sleep workingtime)
    (>!! in :close)
    (>!! in :close)
    (println "closing the shop...")
    (println (str "Served " (<!! barber-ch) " customers"))
    (println (str "Overall " (<!! customers-ch) " customers came"))))
```

Is it a correct solution? Can it be improved to make it more `Clojure`-like?

I wanted to use `alt!` instead of `alts!` which makes code easier to read:

```
(defn barber [in]
  (go-loop [served-customers 0]
           (alt!
             waiting-room (do (Thread/sleep 20)
                              (recur (inc served-customers)))
             in served-customers)))
```

Runtime throws an exception: `Can only recur from tail position`. Can I still use `alt!`?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the `alt!`/`recur` problem by rewriting to:

```
(defn barber [in]
  (go-loop [served-customers 0]
    (if (= :waiting-room
           (a/alt!
             waiting-room ([result] :waiting-room) ;; you could also use result if needed
             in ([result] :in))) ;; same here
      (do (Thread/sleep 20)
          (recur (inc served-customers)))
      served-customers)))
```